# Strange results of Indexing services

Tags: sql-server, full-text-indexing, indexing-service

Currently I am working on Indexing services to search document from Windows server. I am using following Query to search "F-0350"

**Query**

```
Select rank,Filename,Size,HitCount from Scope() where CONTAINS(Contents, 'ISABOUT('F-0350' WEIGHT(1.0))')
```

**Query Result:**

```
 Rank          FileName         Size    HitCount
    572   sf ob-0350.prod.xml   2521    4
    572   sf g-0350.prod.xml    1199    4
    572   sf qa-0350.prod.xml   1864    4
    572   sf f-0350.prod.xml    1551    4
    362   sf ob-0353.prod.xml   2469    4
```

I am expecting 4th record on top but its not coming.

Comment: I have not used this before, but since no-one else is replying... searching google for "where CONTAINS(Contents, 'ISABOUT" (include the double quotes in the search box), I found this page with examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226165%28v=sql.70%29.aspx   and it looks like you need **DOUBLE** quotes, inside your `ISABOUT` -- `"F-0350"` instead of `'F-0350'`.  Please reply with a comment to `@Doug_Ivison`, saying if that helped.

Comment: This SO posting shows more examples with the double quotes I was suggesting... and you might find it helpful in general:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700320/sql-server-isabout-weighted-terms